# Admin first hook that outputs HTML?

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, headers, wp-load.php

I think `load-(page)` is the first hook in the admin screen that deals with outputting HTML, but I'm not totally sure. Basically I'm looking for the equivalent to `template_rediect` or `get_header`, which don't work on the admin side (correct me if I'm wrong).

I'd like to hook into every admin page. My guess using either `$page_now` or `get_current_screen()` but my mind is going blank on how I'd implement them on all pages:

```
$page = get_current_screen()->parent_file;
add_action( 'load-$page.php', 'add_action_all_load_hook', 1, 0 );
```

On the front-end I would do this:

```
function link_rel_buffer_callback($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('ORIGINAL', 'NEW', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}

function link_rel_buffer_start() {
    ob_start("link_rel_buffer_callback");
}
function link_rel_buffer_end() {
    ob_flush();
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'link_rel_buffer_start', -1);
add_action('get_header', 'link_rel_buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'link_rel_buffer_end', 999);
```

I'm thinking the equivalent would be

```
add_action('load-$page', 'link_rel_buffer_end', 1, 0);
add_action('in_admin_footer', 'link_rel_buffer_end', 999);
```

but I can't grasp how to do `load-(page)` on every load.

// UPDATE BASED ON @birgire example

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_admin_init' );
function wpse_admin_init( $buffer )
{
    if( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX') || ! DOING_AJAX )
        ob_start( 'wpse_buffering' );
}

function wpse_buffering( $buffer )
{   
    $buffer = preg_replace('FIND', 'REPLACE', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}


function wpse_buffering_shutdown() {
        ob_flush();
    }
add_action('in_admin_footer', 'wpse_buffering_shutdown', 9999);
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Output buffering. I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one:

```
/**
 * Fires as an admin screen or script is being initialized.
 *
 * Note, this does not just run on user-facing admin screens.
 * It runs on admin-ajax.php and admin-post.php as well.
 *  
 * This is roughly analgous to the more general 'init' hook, which fires earlier.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'admin_init' );
```

if you need a hook activated on every admin page.

For example:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_admin_init' );

function wpse_admin_init( $buffer )
{
    if( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX') || ! DOING_AJAX )
        ob_start( 'wpse_buffering' );
}

function wpse_buffering( $buffer )
{       
    return $buffer;
}
```

ps: If you need to hook into the part after `</html>`, you can use the PHP function [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to run your own callback after the PHP script has finished executing. But notice that then the output buffers have already be sent to the client, according to this [comment on the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php#85014).

Comment: Thanks birgire. I'd mostly just for basic replacement of hardcoded strings where gettext wont work - http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext

Comment: I updated my answer... I wasn't sure on if the regster_shutdown_function() so I didn't feel like messing with it too much since I probably woudn't ever need afterr </html>. Is my update with the ob_flush(); how you'd suggest implementing it?

Comment: I wonder if you need the `ob_flush()`, since the buffer is automatically flushed at the end of the script.